# How does GTK determine its settings?

Tags: gtk

Under Linux, GTK applications look very different when they run under Gnome, XFCE or "vanilla" X11 with no desktop environment. Under some desktop environments, GTK also adapts to HiDPI displays while on others it does not.

I am trying to figure out how a given GTK application figures out how to render itself or - equivalently - how functions like [Gtk.Settings.get_for_screen](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/type_func.Settings.get_for_screen.html) and
[gdk_window_get_scale_factor](https://docs.gtk.org/gdk3/method.Window.get_scale_factor.html) figure out what to return.

Through experiments and internet search, it seems that Gtk settings can be read from configuration files in $HOME, through [xsettings](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/xsettings-spec/xsettings-latest.html) and through environment variables. However, none of this seems to provide means to e.g. set the scale factor so this is likely an incomplete list.

What is the canonical list of configuration sources consulted, their precedence, and what exactly can be specified in each source?